# How to Prevent this Translate-Popup in Chromium of Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, chromium

Box which irritates me daily

[image]

Clicking on the side does not work always immediately. It requires many clicks often. However, I think the best option is to prevent such popups or hovering boxes to appear. 
I do want to have active Google translate but not in such a disturbing way.

Comment: I opened the thread about this also in the official channel here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/F6nmbPHR5Zw;context-place=forum/chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do ([here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/F6nmbPHR5Zw;context-place=forum/chrome))

> 1. Click menu icon and go to Settings.
> 2. Click Show advanced settings.
> 3. Under Language section, uncheck Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language you read.

I added my target language to the list and had then the unchecked option. Solves the case.